# Debugging Http Trigger Azure Function VS 2017

Tags: c#, function, azure

I have Visual Studio 2017 15.3 and have installed the Azure Development workload installed.

I created a blank `HttpTrigger` according to this article:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-microsoft-azure-functions-using-visual-studio-2017/

I can debug successfully if I use `Name` as parameter query string.

However, If I use Postman to create this Post request:

```
{
    "name": "Azure"
}
```

I get the following error:

> "mscorlib: Exception while executing function: HttpTrigger
>   . Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' doe
>   s not contain a definition for 'name'."

Here is my code for the function app in Visual Studio 2017:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace VS2017TestFunctionApp
{
    public static class HttpTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("HttpTrigger")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            // Get request body
            dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

            // Set name to query string or body data
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if I copy the exact same code within the Run function and use the same test post in a function app via the Azure Portal it all works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I create a Azure function app with your code and send a request using Postman, which works fine on my side.

***Request and Response***

[image]

*Request body:*

[image]

***The breakpoint at getting request body can be hit as expected***

[image]

***edit:***

I can extract `name` from `data` without any error.

[image]

Comment: If you move to the next line from your break point to 'name' you should get the error.

Comment: Also, if I copy the exact same code within the Run function and use the same test post in a function app via the Azure Portal it all works fine.

Comment: ``If you move to the next line from your break point to 'name' you should get the error.`` I do not get the error, the code work fine.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I am using .Net 4.6.1. This seems like a versioning issue to me..